# Locus with line segments ratio constant.

Tags: differential-geometry

$OAB$ is a rotating radial ray through origin $O$. Find a continuous curve through A and B so that *quotient* $OA/OB$ is constant, excluding Euclidean motion of rotation around $O$. A and B can also be also on either side of O.

( As a refresher, for such a *product* to be constant its locus is a circle).

EDIT1:

By "continuous" I mean a smooth continuously differentiable curve and possessing continuous $ n^{th}$ order derivatives. Like a circle in the above cited unrelated case example.

EDIT2:

By " Like a circle" means function of curve infinite degree, capable of an infinite series representation.

Comment: If such a ratio is constant, there is an homothety bringing the path described by the $A$ point into the path described by the $B$ point, but assuming the ratio is not $\pm 1$, how can the union of such two paths be  a continuous curve?

Comment: At this time of my  thinking  an answer can be be only vague. The differential relationship of constant quotient of roots of a quadratic equation may have to be examined. For a product case it has been independently derived/ established without prior knowledge of the circle. To reinforce your point, two circles $ r = \cos \theta, r = 2 \cos  \theta $ satisfy the ratio but they are different curves.

Comment: The point is that we may simply drop the assumption that our curve is closed.

Comment: "Find a continuous curve through A and B": what do you mean ???

Comment: Yes, my question was that it should be a continuous curve but need not be closed one like an oval or something. The base 2 log spiral is one correct solution (which supplies a set in geometric progression), but can it be proved as  a general solution?

Comment: You don't answer my question. There is an infinity of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Like for example as Jack D'Aurizio has given, a logarithmic spiral.

Comment: "for such a product to be constant its locus is a circle": among many other possibilities.

Comment: Question is for quotient, not product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a [logarithmic spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral) with polar equation $\rho(\theta)=2^\frac{\theta}{2\pi}$. If $O$ is the origin, $A$ is the image of $\theta_0$ and $B$ is the image of $\theta_0+2\pi$, $O,A,B$ are collinear and $\frac{OB}{OA}=2$.

Anyway, any deformation $\rho(\theta) = h(\theta)\cdot 2^{\frac{\theta}{2\pi}}$ with $h$ being a positive $2\pi$-periodic function works just as well.

Comment: Yes, this particular case is nice continuous one or the same curve, bent enough without    homothety violation... I believe it is a particular solution to an ODE tough enough to formulate at the moment..

Comment: We express it differently but our solutions are essentially the same.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I agree :)

Comment: *If not closed*, I would attempt to  eventually derive a neat solution formed  out of an ODE including the log spiral.

Comment: @Narasimham: There are too many degrees of freedom (the choice of $h$) to write the solutions to your problem as the solutions of an ODE.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio. I have n't worked it out yet, so am not sure. Let me have your comment (With you there the mod may *not* show us to chat..:) ) There are two constants in a quadratic equn, one is fixed up as this ratio, other one is an arbitrary constant ...Just as it is for a circle.. I expect it may be unwieldy but not impossible..

Comment: @Narasimham: I was not speaking about the geometric constraints, I was speaking about the space of solutions, that is an infinity-dimensional space since we are free to take the $h$ function as we like (more or less). Which kind of ODE has a space of solutions so large?

Answer (score 0):

The proof is finally as follows, hope it accommodates all views so far for a differentially continuous solution :

$$ OA = u, \, OB = v ; $$

By the Quotient Rule since $\frac{u}{v} $ is constant

$$  \dfrac{du}{u}= \dfrac{dv}{v} =  c_2 d\theta $$

where we can take the constant differential applicable to both $u,v\,$ as a cross proportionality constant.

Integrating,

$$ c_3 \log u = c_4 \log v  = c_2 \theta + c_5 $$

or,

$$ \dfrac{u}{u_1}= \dfrac{v}{v_1} = c \, e^{c_2 \theta}  $$

which executes $\theta $ rotation on a single log spiral for any $h$ dilatation.